# How to sort a collection of lines from different files?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

I want to sort  second line in each file by second column, and also print name of the corresponding file. I am doing it like this -

```
rm tmp;
for filename in file*; do
  num=`head -2 $filename | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`;
  echo "$filename $num" >> tmp;
done;
sort -n -k2,2 tmp
```

Can it be done in a better way that doesn't include a `tmp` file?

Comment: You could push "$f $num" to an array and then process the array elements. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/bash-add-value-to-array-without-specifying-a-key) shows how to push elements to an array in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 2' file1 file2 filen | sort -n -k2,2
```

With `gawk`, you can use `nextfile` for efficience:

```
$ gawk 'FNR == 2 {print FILENAME,$2; nextfile}' file1 file2 filen | sort -n -k2,2
```

or you can write your own `nextfile` function in other `awk` implementation refer to [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_16.html#SEC143).

If you don't have `gawk`, you can use `perl` for more portable:

```
$ perl -anle 'print "$ARGV $F[1]" and close ARGV if $. == 2' file1 file2 filen |
  sort -n -k2,2
```

Comment: thanks for the awk FNR tip, but I also want to print the filename before sorted column. It needs storing "filename secondColumn" somehow. I think @Warwick's array suggestion will work.

Comment: Thanks it works, what's the purpose of `nextfile` though, it works even without `nextfile`.

Comment: `nextfile` prevent you from reading the rest of file after second line.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in file* ; do { 
    read line
    read na num na
} <"$f"
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$f" "$num"
done | sort -t\<tab> -n -k2,2
```

Though it's hard to tell for sure because you don't note the field separator, the above assumes `awk` defaults but does the job with native shell script, I think.